# problem after installation app

Tags: debian, deb

[image]I've tried to install torguard vpn app, deb files and it did not work. So now everytimes I want to install something or uninstall, I have that kind of error:
(here, I install wine but, still, torguard installation cause problem..... idea? I tried many things, autoremove, clean, purge etc..

```
sudo apt install wine

Reading Package Lists ... Done
Building the dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
E: The torguard package must be reinstalled, but its archive cannot be found.
```

---

still error:

```
$ wget https://torguard.net/downloads/torguard-latest-amd64.deb
--2021-01-17 10: 19: 10-- https://torguard.net/downloads/torguard-latest-amd64.deb
Resolution of torguard.net (torguard.net)… 104.20.89.240, 104.20.88.240
Connection to torguard.net (torguard.net) | 104.20.89.240 |: 443… connected.
HTTP request transmitted, awaiting response ... 200 OK
Size: 20614258 (20M) [application / x-debian-package]
Save to: "torguard-latest-amd64.deb"

torguard-latest-amd64.deb 100% [========================================= ==============================>] 19.66M 12.1MB / s in 1.6s

2021-01-17 10:19:12 (12.1 MB / s) - “torguard-latest-amd64.deb” saved [20614258/20614258]

james @ ninja: ~ $ sudo dpkg -i torguard-latest-amd64.deb
[sudo] Password of james:
(Reading the database ... 179103 files and directories already installed.)
Preparing to unpack torguard-latest-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking torguard (4.3.0) on (4.3.0) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/torguard.postrm: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/torguard.postrm: update-desktop-database: not found
dpkg: warning: old torguard package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: attempting to run the script for the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: update-desktop-database: not found
dpkg: error processing torguard-latest-amd64.deb archive (--install):
 new torguard package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm: update-desktop-database: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new torguard package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Processing of deferred actions ("triggers") for mime-support (3.62) ...
Errors were encountered during execution:
 torguard-latest-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cleanly install `torguard` package:

```
wget https://torguard.net/downloads/torguard-latest-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i torguard-latest-amd64.deb
```

or:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i torguard-latest-amd64.deb
```

Edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/torguard.postrm` replace its content with:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
/bin/true
```

Then run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt -f install
```

**Edit1**:

Edit you `/var/lib/dpkg/status` by removing `torguard` with its description, then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

**Edit2** (solved by)

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/torguard* /tmp
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq torguard
```

Comment: still same issue, thanks btw for your time and help. I removed what was in ''/var/lib/dpkg/info/torguard.postrm''  and put : ''#!/bin/bash
set -e
/bin/true''    above ''exit 0''   and ran the commands but at then same error about torguard must be reinstalled etc......   btw, what about ''torguard.postrm.bak'' ?  did not see it, just ''postrm''

Comment: ok after reboot, I see now .bak file

Comment: @James78 remove it

Comment: I have no option to delete it... weird, mouse right clic or just delete on keyboad, nothing works

Comment: @James78 reboot then switch to TTY.

Comment: ok, run tty and I retry : sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt -f install ?

Comment: @James78 `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/torguard.postrm.bak` then `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: still same error, so I need to reset my debian build I guesss.........?

Comment: @James78 No do not reinstall it , I will edit my answer.

Comment: I followed it, but still same error, really I dont why, all that for a deb installation, amazing.

Comment: @James78 I have update my answer.

Comment: working now, wow, thanks, really.

Comment: @James78 Super! You are welcome.